# Listening to WkWebView's navigate event

Tags: ios, xamarin

I'm new to Xamarin and iOS. I'm trying to create a custom renderer in Xamarin Forms that renders WkWebView. I would like my `DidStartProvisionalNavigation()` method to be called when the user taps on a link in the webview but that's not happening and I don't know why.  I'm trying to use Xlab's [HybridViewRender](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms.iOS/Controls/HybridWebView/HybridWebViewRenderer.cs#L81) as a reference. Can someone tell me how I can get WkWebView to call `DidStartProvisionalNavigation()` when a user taps on a link? Thanks

Here's the source code of my custom IOS renderer that uses WkWebView.

```
public class HybridWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<HybridWebView, WKWebView>, IWKScriptMessageHandler
    {
        const string JavaScriptFunction = "function invokeCSharpAction(data){window.webkit.messageHandlers.invokeAction.postMessage(data);}";
        WKUserContentController userController;

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (e.PropertyName == "Uri") 
                Control.LoadRequest (new NSUrlRequest (new NSUrl (Element.Uri)));
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<HybridWebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged (e);

            if (Control == null) {
                userController = new WKUserContentController ();
                var script = new WKUserScript (new NSString (JavaScriptFunction), WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentEnd, false);
                userController.AddUserScript (script);
                userController.AddScriptMessageHandler (this, "invokeAction");
                var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration { UserContentController = userController };
                config.ApplicationNameForUserAgent += " MethodApp";
                var webView = new WKWebView (Frame, config);

                SetNativeControl (webView);
            }
            if (e.OldElement != null) {
                userController.RemoveAllUserScripts ();
                userController.RemoveScriptMessageHandler ("invokeAction");
                var hybridWebView = e.OldElement as HybridWebView;
                e.OldElement.onRefresh -= Refresh;
                hybridWebView.Cleanup ();
            }
            if (e.NewElement != null) {
                e.NewElement.onRefresh += Refresh;
                //string fileName = Path.Combine (NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, string.Format ("Content/{0}", Element.Uri));
                if (Element.Uri != null) 
                    Control.LoadRequest (new NSUrlRequest (new NSUrl (Element.Uri)));

            }
        }

        public void Refresh(object sender, EventArgs ea) {
            Control.Reload();
        }

        public void DidReceiveScriptMessage (WKUserContentController userContentController, WKScriptMessage message)
        {
            Element.InvokeAction (message.Body.ToString ());
        }

        [Export("webView:didStartProvisionalNavigation:")]
        public void DidStartProvisionalNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
        {
            Element.OnNavigating(webView.Url);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You just need to add this line:

```
webView.NavigationDelegate = this;
```

after the code:

```
var webView = new WKWebView (Frame, config);
```

Also don't forget to change:

```
public class HybridWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer< HybridWebView,WKWebView>, IWKScriptMessageHandler, IWKNavigationDelegate
```

Afterwards, you can use and override the DidStartProvisionalNavigation code:

```
[Export("webView:didStartProvisionalNavigation:")]
public void DidStartProvisionalNavigation(WKWebView webView,WKNavigation navigation)
{
// When navigation starts, this gets called
Console.WriteLine("DidStartProvisionalNavigation");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `DidStartProvisionalNavigation` method is contained in the [IWKNavigationDelegate](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/WebKit.IWKNavigationDelegate/) and `WKWebView`has the property [NavigationDelegate](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/WebKit.WKWebView.NavigationDelegate/)

All you should need is a custom Delegate

```
public class MyNavigationDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate
{
    private readonly HybridWebViewRenderer _renderer;

    public MyNavigationDelegate(HybridWebViewRenderer  renderer)
    {
        _renderer = renderer;
    }

    public override void DidFailProvisionalNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation, NSError error)
    {
        // call methods of your renderer or its properties like
        _renderer.Element.OnNavigating(webView.Url);
    }
}
```

that is set as NavigationDelegate on your webview in your renderer

```
var webView = new WKWebView (Frame, config);
webView.NavigationDelegate = new MyNavigationDelegate(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that

```
public override void DidStartProvisionalNavigation( WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation )
```

needs to be in a delegate class that implements WKNavigationDelegate, that you then assign to your webview's NavigationDelegate property.

This forum [thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/41777/wkwebview-caching-not-working) has some more info on using WKWebView

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that you have set the WeakNavigationDelegate for the WKWebView. The hybrid renderer from XLabs does it here:

```
var webView = new WKWebView(Frame, config) { WeakNavigationDelegate = this };
```

https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms.iOS/Controls/HybridWebView/HybridWebViewRenderer.cs#L133